# How to speed up this calculation using 3 for loops with a complex progress of indices?

Tags: r, performance, loops, indices

Given the following data frame `df` and a numeric vector `p` containing one value:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1, 110), rep(2, 290)),
                 m  = c(seq(1, 110), seq(1:290)),
                 m1 = c(rep(108, 110), rep(288, 290)),
                 m2 = c(rep(3, 400)),
                 f1 = c(rep(-100, 110), rep(-50, 290)),
                 f2 = c(rep(22, 110), rep(15, 290)),
                 f3 = c(rep(5, 110), rep(0, 290)),
                 u  = c(c(0.12, 0.16, 0.10), rep(0, 107), c(0.085, 0.09, 0.11), rep(0, 287)),
                 v  = c(rep(0.175, 3), rep(0, 107), rep(0.115, 3), rep(0, 287)),
                 y  = rep(0, 400))

df$s <- sqrt(df$m/(df$m1 + df$m2 - 1))/40

p <- 0.01
```

Here's a snippet:

```
> head(df)
  id m  m1 m2   f1 f2 f3    u     v y           s
1  1 1 108  3 -100 22  5 0.12 0.175 0 0.002383656
2  1 2 108  3 -100 22  5 0.16 0.175 0 0.003370999
3  1 3 108  3 -100 22  5 0.10 0.175 0 0.004128614
4  1 4 108  3 -100 22  5 0.00 0.000 0 0.004767313
5  1 5 108  3 -100 22  5 0.00 0.000 0 0.005330018
6  1 6 108  3 -100 22  5 0.00 0.000 0 0.005838742
```

Here are some facts about the data:

1. Variables `id` and `m` uniquely identify each row (primary key).
2. Variable `m` means 'month'. The dataset is therefore a time series.
3. Variables `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `m1` and `m2` **are constant** for each value of `id`. These don't depend on variable `m`.
4. Variables `s`, `u` and `v` **are not constant** for each value of `id` and therefore do depend on `m`.
5. The number of rows for each value of `id` equals m1 + m2 - 1. Or equivalent: the maximum value of `m` for each value of `id` equals m1 + m2 - 1.

The goal is to calculate `y` using the formula below:

[image]

[image]

I have created a solution that does just that:

```
counter <- 0
start   <- proc.time()

for(n in 1:nrow(df)){

  #index k holds the current value for m
  k <- df$m[n]
  counter <- counter + 1

  #read the current value for m1 and m2
  m1 <- df$m1[n]
  m2 <- df$m2[n]
  counter <- counter + 2

  #calculate the sum of f1, f2 and f3.
  sum_of_fs <- df$f1[n] + df$f2[n] + df$f3[n]
  counter <- counter + 1

  #initialize y. Set it to zero.
  y <- 0
  counter <- counter + 1

  for(i in k:min(m1 + k - 1, m1 + m2 - 1)){

    #Initialize the sumproduct of u and v. Set it to zero.
    sumprod_uv <- 0
    counter <- counter + 1

    for(j in min(k, m2):max(1, i - m1 + 1)){

      sumprod_uv <- sumprod_uv + df$u[j] + df$v[i - j + 1]
      counter <- counter + 1

    }  

    z <- ((1 + p)/(1 + df$s[i]))^(i / 12)
    y <- y + sumprod_uv * z
    counter <- counter + 2  
  }  

  y <- y * sum_of_fs
  df$y[n] <- y
  counter <- counter + 2
}

counter

proc.time() - start
```

In this piece of code I included 2 extra things:

1. A counter named `counter` that counts the number of statements that are executed.
2. A timer that measures the duration of the script.

Now the complication is that the script takes too long to run. For this toy example it took about 2 seconds (with the counter statements commented out), which is acceptable:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  1.829   0.002   1.872
```

The number of statements this duration corresponds with is 290,188 (value of `counter` when script is done running)

In real life I have a dataset that contains more than 90k records. Besides that, the real dataset is slightly more complicated (7 variables that make up the id instead of one). I ran the script using that dataset and it ran for about 17 minutes.

The question is: how can I speed up this algorithm? There should be a neater way to do this.

Comment: how can value of `counter = 289.788` if you only add an integer number to it?

Comment: you should remove redundant parts of your code that isn't relevant for this question. For example, `sum_of_fs` is not used anywhere in code. Also, `counter` is needed or not?

Comment: @dvd280 that thousands (289k)

Comment: On a more general note, these types of algorithms are kind of bad in native R, consider writing a c++ function and loading it with `Sourcecpp(" function_Name ")` from the `Rcpp` package. Even the way you wrote your code is completely portable to c++. R isn't really designed to deal with non parallel time series. I am saying this because your code isnt benefiting from vectorized operations at all here.

Comment: @dvd280: I accidentally used a dot instead of a comma to seperate thousands. @minem: thanks for your feedback on my code. I made a mistake by not including the variable `sum_of_fs`  to calculate `y`. I've changed the code, so that it is now included in the calculation of `y`.

Comment: @dvd280: considering your comment on the type of algorithm I'm using, are you saying that R is inherently bad at doing these kind of calculations in which the time series are not parallel? Does a solution in which I CAN make use of vectorized operations not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Her you have a *C++* variant which could be faster than in *R*.

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(code = "#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> fun(double &p
, std::vector<int> &dfm
, std::vector<int> &dfm1
, std::vector<int> &dfm2
, std::vector<double> &u
, std::vector<double> &v
, std::vector<double> &s
) {
std::vector<double> yy(s.size());
for(size_t n=0; n<s.size(); ++n) {
  int k = dfm[n];
  int m1 = dfm1[n];
  int m2 = dfm2[n];
  int v1 = std::min(k, m2);
  double y = 0.;
  int ii = std::min(m1 + k - 1, m1 + m2 - 1);
  for(int i=std::min(k,ii); i<=std::max(k,ii); ++i) {
    double sumprod_uv = 0.;
    int jj = std::max(1, i - m1 + 1);
    for (int j=std::min(v1, jj); j<=std::max(v1, jj); ++j) {
      sumprod_uv += u[j-1] + v[i - j];
    }  
    y += sumprod_uv * std::pow(((1. + p)/(1. + s[i-1])), (i / 12.));
  }
  yy[n] = y;
}
return yy;
}")
system.time(df$y <- fun(p, df$m, df$m1, df$m2, df$u, df$v, df$s))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.005   0.000   0.004
```

After the question update including f1, f2, and f3:

```
df$y <- fun(p, df$m, df$m1, df$m2, df$u, df$v, df$s) * (df$f1 + df$f2 + df$f3)
```

For time comparison the timings on my pc:

```
#Your code
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.358   0.004   0.362 

#@minem
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.090   0.003   0.093
```

Comment: Great GKi! Using a C++ function in R is new for me, but I'm going to give it a try!

Comment: I also found some background here https://adv-r.hadley.nz/rcpp.html that provides arguments for the justification of using C++ instead of R.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest improvement should be to redefine columns as vectors before the loop: (+ calculate `v1` in first loop and remove `sum_of_fs` calculation as it isn't used anywhere)

```
# redefine df columns as vectors
dfm <- df$m
dfm1 <- df$m1
dfm2 <- df$m2
u <- df$u
v <- df$v
s <- df$s

start   <- proc.time()
for (n in 1:nrow(df)) {
  k <- dfm[n]
  m1 <- dfm1[n]
  m2 <- dfm2[n]
  v1 <- min(k, m2)
  # sum_of_fs <- df$f1[n] + df$f2[n] + df$f3[n] # not used anywhere !!
  y <- 0
  for (i in k:min(m1 + k - 1, m1 + m2 - 1)) {
    sumprod_uv <- 0
    for (j in v1:max(1, i - m1 + 1)) {
      sumprod_uv <- sumprod_uv + u[j] + v[i - j + 1]
    }  
    z <- ((1 + p)/(1 + s[i]))^(i / 12)
    y <- y + sumprod_uv * z
  }  
  df$y[n] <- y
}
proc.time() - start
```

For me this runs in `0.39` seconds (versus `1.03` seconds for initial approach).
I would suggest to crate more complex data set for speed testing.